# How to turn objects into hyperlinks in R Markdown

Tags: html, r, hyperlink, r-markdown

I have a loop which produces many different HTML R Markdowns that have the same variables but different results in it (based on a single .Rmd).

I would like to insert a hyperlink to an external website, which the only thing that changes in the URL is the name of each of the topics I am dealing with. For this, there would need to have something that is able to change across the loop. However the link structure of R Markdown just allow straightforward links.

Loop script which renders the files:

```
names <- c(name1, name2, name3)

for (name in names){
  rmarkdown::render('document.Rmd',
                    output_file =  paste("document", name, ".html", sep=''))
}
```

For *documentname1.html* the hyperlink code behind would be:

```
[External Website](http://website.com/name1.html)
```

For *documentname2.html* the hyperlink code behind would be:

```
[External Website](http://website.com/name2.html)
```

And so on.

How can I make a link structure that the URL refers to an object in my Rmd base file or if there is an alternative, such as a HTML syntax that can be used for this case?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is

Comment: Having in mind the link structure of R Markdown, which only accepts straightforward URL, how is it possible to make it refer a link (perhaps stored in an object) that will vary according to the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward way with `sed`:

```
library(rmarkdown)
for(name in names) {
    system(paste0("sed \'s/MYNAME/", name, "/g\' ", "document.Rmd > foo.Rmd"))
    render("foo.Rmd", output_file =  paste0("document", name, ".html"))
    unlink("foo.Rmd")
}
```

In your reference `document.Rmd` have `[External Website](http://website.com/MYNAME.html)` and in each iteration replace `MYNAME` with `name` using `sed`.